# Is JTAPI still alive?

Tags: jtapi

I'm investigating how our application can communicate with a phone system: identifying the caller and making a call.

I see that there is a standard Java API: JTAPI with 2 implementations (gjtapi and xtapi). Unfortunately, those projects seems to be dead.

Can I use this API?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you askng here? Is this programming question? Ask in mailing list or support forum.

Comment: I think u can do your task with asterisk too (identifying the caller and making a call.) so why do u need java?

Comment: The idea is to follow standards as much as possible. Our Java application could not rely on a particular client phone infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the phone systems you have to use/connect with :

With Avaya, Unify (Siemens), Cisco you have good support. Asterisk looks outdated.

Other systems? Don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JTapi is still alive but it depends of telefony platform maker. For example:

- For Cisco you have tow options: For Call Manager Express which allows you control just one extension by connection and for Call Manager Enterprise wich allows you control many extensions by connection.
- For Avaya you have another implementation of JTapi wich allows you control one extension by connection.

All of them use the standar of JTapi for implements their requirements according with the telephony plataforma.